# implement reCAPTCHA v3 in WordPress loginscreen

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-api, recaptcha

Google just released a new  beta version of their recaptcha: reCaptcha v3. 
I am trying to implement this in my WordPress login screens. However it does show the recaptcha logo in the bottom right corner (like here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html) which indicates that the script is loaded I can not seem to get it triggered.

What I've done:

1) Enqueued the API script in the header of my login screens (working)

2) Enqueued some js to trigger the captcha

**Enqueues**

```
public static function load_login_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'recaptchav3', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=KEY');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-recaptcha', 'somepath/recaptcha.js' );
}



add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_login_scripts'));
```

**js to trigger the captcha**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('MYKEY', {action: 'login'}).then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);
        });
    });
});
```

This does actually log a (356 characters long) token in the console.

**Good to know**

- I am working on a vagrant development envoirement, thought that might be the problem but the interacting with the api doesn't seem to be held down.
- I am testing in incognito, each time a new session, so this can not be the problem.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Here is the working demo: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true

Comment: @Maartje which version of WordPress you're using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, make sure to enable `JavaScript`. If not, refer to this link at [reCaptcha faq](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#no_js).

I've tested the following code without any error and had reCaptcha Logo in the bottom right corner:

**reCaptchaV3/reCaptchaV3.php**

```
<?php 
/*
 * Plugin Name: reCaptchaV3 Beta
 * Plugin Author: N/A
 * Version: 0.1
 */

final class reCaptchaV3
{

    public function __construct()  { }

    public function init()
    {
        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_login_scripts') );
    }

    public static function load_login_scripts()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'recaptchav3', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITE_KEY');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-recaptcha', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'recaptcha.js' );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', array( new reCaptchaV3(), 'init' ) );
```

**reCaptchaV3/recaptcha.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', {action: 

            'login'}).then(function(token) {
                console.log(token);
            });
    });
});
```

---

**Version Issue**

`login_enqueue_scripts` was available [after WordPress version](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/#changelog) **3.1.0** so make sure to use WordPress version after that.

---

**API Keys**

Get the testing keys from [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#localhost_support), not sure if they work for reCaptcha v3 Beta but I had my registered at [admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin). Although, localhost is not a supported domain so use a virtual host if you're working locally.

If you have added or changed domains in [admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin), it takes 30 minutes to effect the change

Testing Keys:

Site Key:   `6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI`
Secret Key: `6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe`

---

**Accessibility**

If you're not seeing reCaptcha logo, maybe `google.com` is not accessible for script loading. Try to replace it with `recaptcha.net` like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'recaptchav3', 'https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITE_KEY');
```

If you're using Content-Security-Policy (CSP) on your website, please review [reCaptcha faq](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#content_security_policy)

Comment: if you still encounter any issue let me know in the comments

Comment: This, with the addition that in my case specific. The v3 didn't work and had to be replaced by 'invisible'  captcha

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working solution, change the function in your 'functions.php' to this.

```
function load_login_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'recaptchav3', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=KEY');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-recaptcha', '/somepath/recaptcha.js' );
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'load_login_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how this is diffrent from what I already did ? It looks the same to me except for the OOP part in my code where I use add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_login_scripts'));

Comment: Your code not working for me too. I just removed the array($this) -`add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'load_login_scripts');` which working fine.

Comment: Hmm, when I change it to this it breaks :(  . For you its not working because of the differ in using the Class I guess

Comment: Oh, can you try to add this directly in 'functions.php' outside the 'class'? Is that possible?

Comment: I'm coding a plugin(so no functions.php). Also the function gets triggered and executed, just not doing what I want so I'm afraid I'm forgetting something and it's no problem of a wrong include. Even if it was, than it would be bad practice to leave it like that and I'd still had to go on searching why it won't work the way I expect it to.

Comment: Okay, try adding the script directly in 'functions.php' and check whether its working fine. Then we can investigate further.

Comment: Have you allow access for google captcha app. click here for enable captcha https://www.google.com/accounts/UnlockCaptcha

Comment: For more help see this developer doc https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3