# Adding reCAPTCHA v3 to wordpress Comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, recaptcha, captcha

Hy,
i've just found how to add it do login page, but how it works with wordpress comments?
[implement reCAPTCHA v3 in WordPress loginscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376912/implement-recaptcha-v3-in-wordpress-loginscreen)

I also use Contact Form 7 witth this solution:
https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/

Can somehow please help how to integrate it also in comments area

Comment: What are you asking? You want to know how to add it to a comment form?

Comment: Yes of course. Either with it or simple to add it with some Snippets.

Comment: How is your comment form made? is it from a template or a plugin? You need to be more specific on what you are seeking and how your environment is configured. The link shows you exactly how to set-up reCaptcha v3

Comment: Its the standard WP Commentform.
That's why i'm not specified than this.

I think i understand the basics`of the script, but how to integrate it in the standard  wp comment form?

This script is configured to add in the loginscreen, right?
So what i need to change to work it is used in the commentform, some of the arrays?!
Something in this line: add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'load_login_scripts');
But here is my ending of understand coding and the scripts

Answer (score 0):

Considering your experience I would go with a plugin to achieve what you are looking for.
Something like this should do the trick and works with the default comment form.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/recaptcha-in-wp-comments-form/