# How to Add ReCAPTCHA to the WordPress Login Page without plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to add recaptcha to WordPress login page without plugin, how should I do this?

Comment: Here it's already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376912/implement-recaptcha-v3-in-wordpress-loginscreen

Comment: Agree with previous

Answer (score 1):

firstly, Register your site in google captcha.
then, create the form in google captcha and get the keys...
put these keys in your **wp-login.php** file in the form after password input.